# Why do I need to put spaces inside arrays in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why does the first line below work, while the second doesn't?

```
$('#myDiv').animate({ height: '100%' }, { queue: false, duration: 100 });

$('#myDiv').animate({height: '100%'}, {queue: false, duration: 100});
```

The only difference between them is the spaces inside the arrays.

Comment: There's no reason why the second shouldn't work. The spaces are irrelevant.

Comment: First, I don't see _any_ arrays here. Second, parameter lists and object literals are space insensative in JS in such cases.

Comment: What does your JS console show?

Comment: +1 there must be something else going on here.

Comment: I don't believe you, Alexandre

Comment: Can you provide an example of the issue on jsfiddle? But it's really strange...

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but did you copy-paste the code without space from web? Sometimes you can copy some invisible characters, and those can trigger an error.

Comment: Teemu, fact is that without spaces, the code didn't work... i had to put spaces for it to work... but i found the issue... my templating engine was misconfigured and outputting conflicting characters for the encoding i'm using... sorry for screaming for help so soon, but i was a bit like "wtf, never seen this happen before!" :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry but I don't know how did you got that conclusion, but it seems to work fine for me.

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mhcgolds/gJdS6/1/).

```
$('#div1').animate({height:'100px'},{queue:false,duration:100});
$('#div2').animate({ height: '100px' }, { queue: false, duration: 100 });
```

I remove all spaces from the first ones and it still get working.

Comment: I just tested in fiddle and it works there.

Comment: but testing it in firefox just hangs the code and nothing shows. :(

Comment: i just found it. somehow the character encoding of my file was messed up and the console just kept saying "character encoding not defined" or something like that.

Comment: For worked on IE, Chrome and FF. You got any errors? There's no syntax errors!! =s

Comment: the console said "The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.

but solved. thanks a lot!